# Polymer - starter kit init behind proxy?

Tags: macos, github, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I'm trying to complete the [Polymer tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/toolbox/set-up) on a Mac. However, upon trying to load the starter kit, I run into the following error:

> ? Which starter template would you like to use? polymer-2-starter-kit
>   info:    Running template polymer-2-starter-kit... info:    Finding
>   latest ^3.0.0 release of PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit error:
>   Uncaught exception: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.github.com
>   api.github.com:443 error:   Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
>   api.github.com api.github.com:443
>       at __dirname.sendError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:838:19)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:849:29
>       at callCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:713:17)
>       at ClientRequest. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:791:17)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at connectErrorNT (net.js:1021:8) 1147425-FVFTM15DH3QK:Polymer test

I'm pretty sure this is because of the company proxy I'm behind. However, trying to launch it by explicitly stating the proxy (eg. `https_proxy=http://proxy:port http_proxy=http://proxy:port polymer init polymer-2-starter-kit`) results in the same.
How can I make sure the starter kit loads? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to Set proxies

For GitHub the commands are

```
git config --global http.proxy whatever-url

git config --global https.proxy whaterver-url
```

You will even need to do those at node Level, as when it tries to do npm install it will need those.

The commands are

```
npm config set proxy whatever-url

npm config set https-proxy whatever-url
```

While the starter kit tries to do bower install, it will fail as it is behind proxy.

Create a .bowerrc file & Keep the following contents there

```
{
    "directory": "bower_components",
    "proxy": "whatever url",
    "https-proxy": "whatever url"
}
```

Comment: This helped install Bower, but the starter kit still doesn't work (same error).

Comment: u tried the following steps
1. create polymer project
2. when it tries to do bower install press Ctrl + C 
3. create .bowerrc in the created file structure
4. now do bower install
5. then do polymer serve

Comment: I tried following: `polymer init polymer-2-starter-kit` and the error shows up.

Comment: Doesnt offer to select you template ???
Do 
Npm cache clean and again install polymer cli

Comment: It does, the template is `polymer-2-starter-kit`.

Comment: with the proxies set, now do npm cache clean & Install again

Comment: It does work from home (no proxy), but with the proxy, the starter kit just won't load.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old thread but I just came across same issue. As this issue is fixed in ploymer-cli [here](https://github.com/a1626/polymer-cli/commit/eea96ccdd8258933b0756d754fdc4e0d3bf03153)

So if you are on Linux run following to set http and https proxy

```
export HTTP_PROXY='http://<proxyhost>:<port>' 
export HTTPS_PROXY='http://<proxyhost>:<port>'
```

Note: Please use HTTP_PROXY not the http_proxy (lower case) as above mentioned fix made uses upper case key. I wasted quite some time since I was setting proxy using lower case